# Group by clause with count() and where condition in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Table : Class**

```
id   Institute_id     Name  
------------------------------
1    1                MCAL - 1  
2    1                MCAL - 2
3    1                BCA - 1
4    1                BCA - 2
```

**Table : Groups**

```
id  Class_Id   Institute_Id   Name          Status
--------------------------------------------------
1   1           1             PHP           false   
2   2           1             JAVA          false               
3   1           1             ORACLE        false
4   2           1             LINUX         true
5   2           1             ASP.NET       false   
6   3           1             OS            false
7   4           2             CPP           false
```

**Expected Result :**

```
id    Name          Count(*)
-----------------------------

1     MCAL - 1        2
2     MCAL - 2        2
3     BCA - 1         1
4     BCA - 2         0
```

> Note: count only those records from Groups where Institute_Id = 1 and Status=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
 Select 
    c.id,
    c.name, 
    SUM(case when g.class_id is NULL then 0 else 1 end) as count 
from class c left join groups g 
   on c.id=g.class_id 
     and g.status='false' 
     and g.Institute_id=1
group by c.id,c.name
order by c.id
```

fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2b992/6

Answer (score 0):

To count properly with outer joins, specify the column name instead of * in `COUNT()`.

```
SELECT C.id, C.Name, [Count] = COUNT(G.Status)
FROM Class C
LEFT JOIN Groups G ON C.id = G.Class_id AND G.Institute_id = 1 AND G.Status = 'false'
GROUP BY C.id, C.Name
ORDER BY C.id
```